# Get previous values of a variable

Tags: r

I have a data frame with observations stored as

```
> m

    ID       Date count Day Month
1  111 2011-05-22     0 Sun   May
2  111 2011-05-23     5 Mon   May
3  111 2011-05-24     5 Tue   May
4  111 2011-05-25     2 Wed   May
5  111 2011-05-26     2 Thu   May
6  112 2011-05-22     2 Sun   May
7  112 2011-05-23     2 Mon   May
8  112 2011-05-24     1 Tue   May
9  111 2011-05-25     0 Wed   May
10 112 2011-05-26     6 Thu   May
```

I need to add a couple of columns that add past values of 'count' variable corresponding to ID and date. For example, for ID 111, I need to what was the sum of count one day ago, two days ago, three days ago, or any other time frame for each date and the correspondingly for each ID.

The desired output would be like

```
> m

    ID       Date count Day Month TwoDaysSum ThreeDaysSum
1  111 2011-05-22     0 Sun   May         NA           NA
2  111 2011-05-23     5 Mon   May         NA           NA
3  111 2011-05-24     5 Tue   May          5           NA
4  111 2011-05-25     2 Wed   May         10           10
5  111 2011-05-26     2 Thu   May          7            7
6  112 2011-05-22     2 Sun   May         NA           NA
7  112 2011-05-23     2 Mon   May         NA           NA
8  112 2011-05-24     1 Tue   May          4           NA
9  111 2011-05-25     0 Wed   May          3            5
10 112 2011-05-26     6 Thu   May          1            3
```

Eventually I need to go back to find the sum for larger time frames like a month/quarter/year.

Does anybody have an idea how to go about it?

Comment: Just one vote: I'm not clear on what your TwoDaysSum or ThreeDaysSum columns are actually calculating. Can you show us how to compute the expected values there? Then maybe we can help figure out how to process the whole data.frame.

Comment: Sounds like a case for `rollapply` from `xts`

Comment: Jeff, count measures the number of times a particular incident occurred at a given place (ID) and at a given date (Date). What I need to figure out is how many times did this incident occur in the last 7 days, 14 days, month, year for each ID separately.
Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
DF<-read.table(text=" ID       Date count Day Month
1  111 2011-05-22     0 Sun   May
2  111 2011-05-23     5 Mon   May
3  111 2011-05-24     5 Tue   May
4  111 2011-05-25     2 Wed   May
5  111 2011-05-26     2 Thu   May
6  112 2011-05-22     2 Sun   May
7  112 2011-05-23     2 Mon   May
8  112 2011-05-24     1 Tue   May
9  112 2011-05-25     0 Wed   May #fixed typo
10 112 2011-05-26     6 Thu   May",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F,sep="")

#sort to be safe
DF<-DF[order(DF$ID,DF$Date),]

DF$TwoDaysSum<-ave(DF$count,DF$ID,FUN=function(x) filter(x,c(0,1,1),sides=1))
DF$ThreeDaysSum<-ave(DF$count,DF$ID,FUN=function(x) filter(x,c(0,1,1,1),sides=1))

DF

    ID       Date count Day Month TwoDaysSum ThreeDaysSum
1  111 2011-05-22     0 Sun   May         NA           NA
2  111 2011-05-23     5 Mon   May         NA           NA
3  111 2011-05-24     5 Tue   May          5           NA
4  111 2011-05-25     2 Wed   May         10           10
5  111 2011-05-26     2 Thu   May          7           12
6  112 2011-05-22     2 Sun   May         NA           NA
7  112 2011-05-23     2 Mon   May         NA           NA
8  112 2011-05-24     1 Tue   May          4           NA
9  112 2011-05-25     0 Wed   May          3            5
10 112 2011-05-26     6 Thu   May          1            3
```